# Python: My program restarts when a function checks if variable > 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error

My program is supposed to stop when a variable is equal to 0 or less, but when the program runs, if the variable is greater than 0 the code resets.

Here is my code:
Main.py

```
import random
import os 
import sys
global foodamount
foodamount = random.randint(1,10)
answer = str(input(("Right or Left")))
if answer == "Right" or answer == "right":
  #Check if foodamount is greater than 1, then if it is run cave.py
  foodamount = foodamount -1
  if foodamount < 1:
    print("You ran out of food. You lose")
    sys.exit()
  if foodamount > 0:
    os.system('python cave.py')
```

This is cave.py

```js
import random
import sys
import os
import main
print("Do you want to attack?")
attak = str(input(("Yes or No")))
if attak == "Yes" or attak == "yes":
  x = random.randint(1,2)
  if x == 1:
    os.system('python attack')
    
  if x == 2:
    
    print("You lose")
    sys.exit()
if attak == "no" or attak == "No":
  print("Do you leave the cave or go around the spider?")
  y = str(input("Leave or Around"))
  if y == "Leave" or y == "leave":
    main.foodamount = main.foodamount -1
    if main.foodamount < 1:
      print("You ran out of food. You lose")
      sys.exit()
    else:
      os.system('python test')
```

When i run this in python, the program starts from beginning, the program restarts from the beginning.

If you could help with this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more context to the question. Without knowing what `cave.py` does its hard to say what is wrong with this code. I did check this code with the value 0 and it exit the code fine so I suspect the problem lies in cave.py

Comment: Is cave.py the name of the file holding this code?

Comment: This is cave.py: ihttps://pastebin.com/hakdunSz

Comment: Main.py holds the code. Cave.py is a second module for the cave section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program restarts because you got the imports all wrong. I am not sure what the proper output is supposed to be but I solved your code so it doesn't restart before doing what it is supposed to do. I hope this helps. Lastly, you need to have both files in the same directory for them to work.

Main.py

```
import random
import os 
import sys
import cave

foodamount = random.randint(1,10)

def main():
    global foodamount

    answer = str(input(("Right or Left")))

    if answer == "Right" or answer == "right":
        #Check if foodamount is greater than 1, then if it is run cave.py
        foodamount = foodamount -1

        if foodamount < 1:
            print("You ran out of food. You lose", foodamount)
            sys.exit()
        elif foodamount > 0:
            os.system('python cave.py')        
main()
```

cave.py

```
import random
import sys
import os
from Main import *

print("You are in a cold section of the cave")
print("You see a spider in front of you")
print("Do you want to attack?")

attak = str(input(("Yes or No")))

if attak == "Yes" or attak == "yes":
    x = random.randint(1,2)
    if x == 1:
        os.system('python attack')     
    if x == 2:
        print("You lose")
        sys.exit()

if attak == "no" or attak == "No":
    print("Do you leave the cave or go around the spider?")
    y = str(input("Leave or Around"))
    if y == "Leave" or y == "leave":
        foodamount = foodamount -1
        if foodamount < 1:
            print("You ran out of food. You lose")
            sys.exit()
        else:
            os.system('python test')
```

Comment: I checked it out, it says 'import main' and I don't have your main file. What is that about?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have written a script which runs itself at the end if certain conditions are met.  Don't do this.  Instead, write a function which implements your game logic, and run that function in a "while" loop, like this:

```
def play_game():
    if the player dies:
        return False
    return True

while play_game():
    pass
```